# Why does FFTW use ptrdiff_t (instead of e.g. size_t) for sizes?

Tags: c, types, fftw

The [FFTW library](https://fftw.org/fftw3_doc/) uses the C type `ptrdiff_t` in its interface to specify large array sizes, in particular in its [“64-bit guru interface”](https://fftw.org/fftw3_doc/64_002dbit-Guru-Interface.html):

> ```
> fftw_plan fftw_plan_guru64_dft(
>      int rank, const fftw_iodim64 *dims,
>      int howmany_rank, const fftw_iodim64 *howmany_dims,
>      fftw_complex *in, fftw_complex *out,
>      int sign, unsigned flags);
> ```
>
> The `fftw_iodim64` type is similar to `fftw_iodim`, with the same
> interpretation, except that it uses type `ptrdiff_t` instead of type
> `int`.
>
> ```
> typedef struct {
>      ptrdiff_t n;
>      ptrdiff_t is;
>      ptrdiff_t os;
> } fftw_iodim64;
> ```

and its [MPI functions](https://fftw.org/fftw3_doc/FFTW-MPI-Reference.html), e. g.:

> ```
> ptrdiff_t fftw_mpi_local_size_2d(ptrdiff_t n0, ptrdiff_t n1, MPI_Comm comm,
>                                  ptrdiff_t *local_n0, ptrdiff_t *local_0_start);
> ptrdiff_t fftw_mpi_local_size_3d(ptrdiff_t n0, ptrdiff_t n1, ptrdiff_t n2,
>                                  MPI_Comm comm,
>                                  ptrdiff_t *local_n0, ptrdiff_t *local_0_start);
> ptrdiff_t fftw_mpi_local_size(int rnk, const ptrdiff_t *n, MPI_Comm comm,
>                               ptrdiff_t *local_n0, ptrdiff_t *local_0_start);
>
> ptrdiff_t fftw_mpi_local_size_2d_transposed(ptrdiff_t n0, ptrdiff_t n1, MPI_Comm comm,
>                                             ptrdiff_t *local_n0, ptrdiff_t *local_0_start,
>                                             ptrdiff_t *local_n1, ptrdiff_t *local_1_start);
> ptrdiff_t fftw_mpi_local_size_3d_transposed(ptrdiff_t n0, ptrdiff_t n1, ptrdiff_t n2,
>                                             MPI_Comm comm,
>                                             ptrdiff_t *local_n0, ptrdiff_t *local_0_start,
>                                             ptrdiff_t *local_n1, ptrdiff_t *local_1_start);
> ptrdiff_t fftw_mpi_local_size_transposed(int rnk, const ptrdiff_t *n, MPI_Comm comm,
>                                          ptrdiff_t *local_n0, ptrdiff_t *local_0_start,
>                                          ptrdiff_t *local_n1, ptrdiff_t *local_1_start);
> ```

> ```
> fftw_plan fftw_mpi_plan_dft_1d(ptrdiff_t n0, fftw_complex *in, fftw_complex *out,
>                                MPI_Comm comm, int sign, unsigned flags);
> fftw_plan fftw_mpi_plan_dft_2d(ptrdiff_t n0, ptrdiff_t n1,
>                                fftw_complex *in, fftw_complex *out,
>                                MPI_Comm comm, int sign, unsigned flags);
> fftw_plan fftw_mpi_plan_dft_3d(ptrdiff_t n0, ptrdiff_t n1, ptrdiff_t n2,
>                                fftw_complex *in, fftw_complex *out,
>                                MPI_Comm comm, int sign, unsigned flags);
> fftw_plan fftw_mpi_plan_dft(int rnk, const ptrdiff_t *n, 
>                             fftw_complex *in, fftw_complex *out,
>                             MPI_Comm comm, int sign, unsigned flags);
> fftw_plan fftw_mpi_plan_many_dft(int rnk, const ptrdiff_t *n,
>                                  ptrdiff_t howmany, ptrdiff_t block, ptrdiff_t tblock,
>                                  fftw_complex *in, fftw_complex *out,
>                                  MPI_Comm comm, int sign, unsigned flags);
> ```

However, this seems strange to me:

- None of these quantities can ever have a valid negative value, so why use a signed type instead of (e. g.) `size_t`, which is exactly the type meant for array sizes? This is even more puzzling because `fftw_malloc(size_t n)` *does* use `size_t` for its argument, and the documentation always states that all of these size arguments must not be negative.
- In particular for MPI, I don’t see why `ptrdiff_t` (or even `size_t`) was chosen, since the data to transform could be distributed across multiple machines, and could thus (in principle) be larger than a single machine could hold in a single array (i. e. larger than `SIZE_MAX`). Wouldn’t `uintmax_t` (or even `intmax_t`) be more appropriate?

Comment: One might equally ask, “Why use `size_t` if the value is never larger than 0x7fffffffffffffff?” Note: If the data is larger than SIZE_MAX, then you’ve got more than 18 exabytes of data (18 million terabytes). Safe to say that nobody is doing Fourier transforms that large.

Comment: @DietrichEpp The maximum value of `ptrdiff_t` is implementation-defined and not always 0x7fffffffffffffff. Similarly, having data larger than `SIZE_MAX` does not mean that it is larger than 18 exabytes of data – the only requirement on `SIZE_MAX` is that it is at least 65535 (64 kiB!).

Comment: Are you sure there aren't **any** cases throughout the library where a negative value makes sense?  Say, as a return value indicating an error?  The most natural situation for such a type is "I want to be able to return any size, including 0, but also an out-of-band value for errors".  POSIX uses `ssize_t` for this, but ISO C doesn't provide it.

Comment: By the way, `intmax_t` and `uintmax_t` were introduced in C99 and are optional for implementations to provide, whereas `ptrdiff_t` is C89 and is mandatory.  Since fftw dates to 1997, it makes sense that it wouldn't have baked C99 features (optional ones at that) into its API.

Comment: @NateEldredge I had the same thought and checked the documentation to see if negative values were used e. g. for errors, and couldn’t find anything where this was the case. In any case, this argument doesn’t apply for user-supplied arguments. Version 3 of FFTW (which I’m referring to here) features a redesigned API compared to earlier versions and dates to 2003, so C99 definitely already existed then. Why do you say that `intmax_t` and `uintmax_t` are optional? In my version of the standards document, § 7.18.1.5 Greatest-width integer types says “These types are required.”

Comment: @Socob: You're right, my mistake.  `intNN_t` are optional but `intmax_t` is required.

Comment: @socob: I didn’t mention how the limits are defined in the C standard because it would be unnecessary, pedantic, and a waste of everyone’s time. I hope, in the future, you will also show restraint.

Comment: @DietrichEpp I’m not sure what you’re talking about and why your tone seems to be getting hostile. Are you implying that one would only ever run FFTW on AMD64-based systems?

Comment: @Socob: You asked about the reason one would choose size_t or ptrdiff_t. There is really nothing in the standard that illuminates how wide these are, in practice, since they’re all connected to implementation-defined limits. However, in practice, on common modern systems, you’ll find that they’re both as wide as a pointer—just unsigned and signed. I illustrated the difference between with an example, to show that you could not use the types’ ranges to choose. It seems like you’re unhappy that I used an example—but as written this question should be closed, so I did not write a full answer.